# Width of the my navbar is not taking 100% of the screen using CSS?

Tags: css, sass, responsive-design

Hello I am having a little problem while my app a responsive one on web, When I resize my browser everything looks fine but when I choose responsive options I get the problem, it looks like my navbar is taking about 90% of the screen width rather than 100%, here is my SASS code : ( I am using mixins )

```
.co-menu-left {

width:110px;
height: 92%;
position: fixed;
top: 70px;
left:0px;
transition: 0.4s all ease;
z-index: 5;

@include responsive(phone){
    width:100vw;
    top:0px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:1500000;
}

}
```

and here is how it looks when I make my browser smaller ( phone in for 600 px and less ) :

[image]

That is the expected for sure, so it works as I intend it, but I choose Galaxy 5 option or iPhone 6/7/8 my problem is there again, and here is how it looks : [image]

You see that undesirable space in the right That I want it to get off, I need help because I feel like my logic is right.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Are you just resizing your browser to a smaller width? Have you tried refreshing the page at the Galaxy 5 size?

Comment: @afishintaiwan yes I refreshed my page many times and the problem remain the same in the Galaxy 5 and iPhone 5/6/7

Comment: @MrLister I think the problem is very clear, I have a fixed div, its width is 110px and become 100vw when The screen width is 600px or less but it does not work properly in Galaxy 5 and iPhone 5/6/7, what do you need more ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use overflow-y: hidden; to remove the scrollbar. hope it helps

Comment: That was not a scrollbar what you saw in the right, it is what is underneath of the navbar, I know they look similar but it is just an accident, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

set the `left` property in the responsive mode too. if didn't work set the width using percentage (`width: 100%`). also make sure there is no unwanted margin on your navbar or it's children. these are the cases I could think of.